# Date parameters in Pentaho Report designer are causing report not to show results?

Tags: pentaho-report-designer

I have a report in report designer connected to Teradata. I am using a date picker with the date parameters in report designer. My query in Teradata works, but in report designer, there are no results when I run it. I beleive it is due to the date parameters. Is there anything that anyone knows of that would cause this?

When I hard code dates, the report shows results. When I add the parameters ${StartDate} and ${EndDate} the report pulls no results.

Comment: Are you using Date or Date(SQL) as parameter type?